# Assign child processes to multiple users

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, child-process, spawn

I have a more general question, maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

I´ve made an app with user accounts and authentification. 
Every account makes it´s own API query once every minute.

Is ist possible to assign every useraccount a dedicated child process?

The procedure could be like this:

1. User sets up an account
2. User starts child process
3. User Logs out
4. child process keeps running (writing to dadabase)
5. User logs in, reads data
6. User retrieves the running process, stops or changes the process

I´m looking around for a while now and can't find anything.
My idea is, to give every child process a unique name.
But maybe my approach goes in the wrong direction.

Thank you for every help.

Comment: Every child process already has an id -> https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_pid

Comment: @Keith So, my approach is in general right?